# Split a Binary Tree using specific methods

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, I have to return a tree containing all elements that smaller than k, greater than k and a tree containing only one element - k.
Allowed methods to use:
**remove node** - O(n)
**insert** - O(n)
**find** - O(n)
**find min** - O(n)
I'm assuming these methods complexity, because in the exercise it's not written that tree is balanced.
**Required complexity** - O(n)
Original tree have to maintain its structure.
I'm completely stuck. Any help is much appreciated!

Given tree is Binary search tree as well as outputs should be binary search trees.

Comment: Is it a binary search tree ?

Comment: There is not enough information. For example, if the output trees can be degenerate trees (none of the nodes has a left child), so more like linked lists, then insertion is constant. So then the overall process is O(n) and quite trivial. If the tree is a binary search tree, and the outputs must be binary search trees as well, we have maybe a more interesting problem.

Comment: @trincot thank you for the correction. Yes, all trees discussed are BTS. Updated the question.

Comment: Are you allowed to navigate through the tree, like perform a binary search step by step, without using the blackbox `find` function?

Comment: Could you come back to us? In the mean time there are several answers, without any reaction from you...

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to design a *O(n)* algorithm with the given blackbox functions and their time complexities, given that they could only be called a (maximum) constant number of times (like 3 times) to stay within the *O(n)* constraint.

But if it is allowed to access and create BSTs with basic, standard node manipulations (traversing via left or right child, setting the left or right child to a given subtree), then you could do the following:

Create three new empty BSTs that will be populated and returned. Name them `left`, `mid`, and `right`, where the first one will have all values less than *k*, the second one will have at the most one node (with value *k*), and the final one will have all the rest.
While populating `left` and `right`, maintain references to the nodes that are *closest* to value *k*: in `left` that will be the node with the greatest value, and in `right` the node with the least value.

Follow these steps:

- Apply the usual binary search to walk from the root towards the node with value *k*
- While doing this: whenever you choose the left child of a node, the node itself and its right subtree then belong in `right`. However, the left child should at this moment not be included, so create a new node that copies the current node, but without its left child. Maintain a reference to the node with the least value in `right`, as that is the node that may get a left new subtree when this step occurs more than once.
- Do the similar thing for when you choose the right child of a node.
- When the node with *k* is found, the algorithm can add its left subtree to `left` and the right subtree to `right`, and create the single-node tree with value `k`.

### Time complexity

The search towards the node with value *k* could take *O(n)* in the worst case, as the BST is not given to be balanced. All the other actions (adding a subtree to a specific node in one of the new BSTs) run in constant time, so in total they are executed *O(n)* times in the worst case.

If the given BST is balanced (not necessarily perfectly, but like with AVL rules), then the algorithm runs in *O(logn)* time. However, the output BSTs may not be as balanced, and may violate AVL rules so that rotations would be needed.

### Example Implementation

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. When you run this snippet, a test case will run one a BST that has nodes with values 0..19 (inserted in random order) and *k*=10. The output will iterate the three created BSTs in in-order, so to verify that they output 0..9, 10, and 11..19 respectively:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    insert(value) { // Insert as a leaf, maintaining the BST property
        if (value < this.value) {
            if (this.left !== null) {
                return this.left.insert(value);
            }
            this.left = new Node(value);
            return this.left;
        } else {
            if (this.right !== null) {
                return this.right.insert(value);
            }
            this.right = new Node(value);
            return this.right;
        }
    }
    // Utility function to iterate the BST values in in-order sequence
    * [Symbol.iterator]() {
        if (this.left !== null) yield * this.left;
        yield this.value;
        if (this.right !== null) yield * this.right;
    }
}

// The main algorithm
function splitInThree(root, k) {
    let node = root;
    // Variables for the roots of the trees to return:
    let left = null;
    let mid = null;
    let right = null;
    // Reference to the nodes that are lexically closest to k:
    let next = null;
    let prev = null;

    while (node !== null) {
        // Create a copy of the current node
        newNode = new Node(node.value);
        if (k < node.value) {
            // All nodes at the right go with it, but it gets no left child at this stage
            newNode.right = node.right;
            // Merge this with the tree we are creating for nodes with value > k
            if (right === null) {
                right = newNode;
            } else {
                next.left = newNode;
            }
            next = newNode;
            node = node.left;
        } else if (k > node.value) {
            // All nodes at the left go with it, but it gets no right child at this stage
            newNode.left = node.left;
            // Merge this with the tree we are creating for nodes with value < k
            if (left === null) {
                left = newNode;
            } else {
                prev.right = newNode;
            }
            prev = newNode;
            node = node.right;
        } else {
            // Create the root-only tree for k
            mid = newNode;
            // The left subtree belongs in the left tree
            if (left === null) {
                left = node.left;
            } else {
                prev.right = node.left;
            }
            // ...and the right subtree in the right tree
            if (right === null) {
                right = node.right;
            } else {
                next.left = node.right;
            }
            // All nodes have been allocated to a target tree
            break;
        }
    }
    // return the three new trees:
    return [left, mid, right];
}

// === Test code for the algorithm ===

// Utility function
function shuffled(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

// Create a shuffled array of the integers 0...19
let arr = shuffled([...Array(20).keys()]);
// Insert these values into a new BST:
let root = new Node(arr.pop());
for (let val of arr) root.insert(val);

// Apply the algorithm with k=10
let [left, mid, right] = splitInThree(root, 10); 

// Print out the values from the three BSTs:
console.log(...left);  // 0..9
console.log(...mid);   // 10
console.log(...right); // 11..19
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your goal is to create a valid BST where k is the root node; in this case, the left subtree is a BST containing all elements less than k, and the right subtree is a BST containing all elements greater than k.

This can be achieved by a series of [tree rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation):

- First, do an O(n) search for the node of value k, building a stack of its ancestors up to the root node.
- While there are any remaining ancestors, pop one from the stack, and perform a tree rotation making k the parent of this ancestor.

Each rotation takes O(1) time, so this algorithm terminates in O(n) time, because there are at most O(n) ancestors. In a balanced tree, the algorithm takes O(log n) time, although the result is not a balanced tree.

In your question you write that "insert" and "remove" operations take O(n) time, but that this is your *assumption*, i.e. it is not stated in the question that these operations take O(n) time. If you are operating only nodes you already have pointers to, then basic operations take O(1) time.

If it is required not to destroy the original tree, then you can begin by making a copy of it in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see a simple and efficient way to split with the operations that you mention. But I think that achieving a very efficient split is relatively easy.

If the tree were balanced, then you can perform your split in O(log n) if you define a special operation called join exclusive. Let me first define `join_ex()` as the operation in question:

```
Node * join_exclusive(Node *& ts, Node *& tg)
  {
    if (ts == NULL)
      return tg;

    if (tg == NULL)
      return ts;

    tg=.llink) = join_exclusive(ts->rlink, tg->llink);

    ts->rlink = tg;
    Node * ret_val = ts;
    ts = tg = NULL; // empty the trees

    return ret_val;
  }
```

`join_ex()` assumes that you want to build a new tree from two BST `ts` and `tr` such that every key in `ts` is less than everyone in `tr`.

If you have two exclusive trees `T<` and `T>`:

[image: Two exclusive trees]

Then `join_ex()` can be seen as follows:

[image: join_ex(T<, T>)]

Note that if you take any node for any BST, then its subtrees meet this condition; every key in the left subtree is less than everyone in the right one. You can design a nice deletion algorithm based on `join_ex()`.

Now we are ready for the split operation:

```
void split_key_rec(Node * root, const key_type & key, Node *& ts, Node *& tg)
  {
    if (root == NULL)
      {
        ts = tg = NULL;
        return;
      }

    if (key < root->key)
      {
        split_key_rec(root->llink, key, ts, root->llink);         
        tg = root;
       }
     else
       {
         split_key_rec(root->rlink, key, root->rlink, tg)
         ts = root;
       }
  }
```

If you set `root` as `T` in this figure

[image: Tree to split]

Then a pictorial representation of split can be seen thus:

[image: split_key_rec(T, k, T<, T>)]

`split_key_rec()` splits the tree into two trees `ts` and `tg` according to a key `k`. At the end of the operation, `ts` contains a BST with keys less than `k` and `tg` is a BST with keys greater or equal than `k`.

Now, to complete your requirement, you call `split_key_rec(t, k, ts, tg)` and you get in `ts` a BST with all the keys less than `k`. Almost symmetrically, you get in `tg` a BST with all the keys greater or equal than `k`. So, the last thing is to verify if the root of `tg` is `k` and, if this is the case, you unlink, and you get your result in `ts`, `k`, and `tg'` (`tg'` is the tree without `k`).

If `k` is in the original tree, then the root of `tg` will be `k`, and `tg` won't have left subtree.